# PHP Regular IF statement V.S Shorthand IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement

My PHP snippet

```
function CheckNumber($number){
 if($number==100){
   return true;
 else{
   return false;
 };
}
```

I want the shorthand (Ternary operator) `if` statement to do the same thing, but this doesn't work:

```
function CheckNumber($number){
  $result = ($number==100) ? return true : return false;
  echo $result;
}
```

I know `echo` is definitely wrong here, but what should I do to return the result of `result` to the function?

Comment: `=` assigns, I think  you want `==` for equality (or probably `===`).

Comment: And `false` instead of `fasle`. And an if statement is silly in the first place, just do `return ($number == 100);`

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo. The question remains

Comment: By the way, it's called a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) rather than a "shorthand if statement". Knowing the proper name will help you search for answers more efficiently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return $number == 100;
```

`==` already results in a boolean, no need to do an `if` on it and create another boolean for it. You also don't need to assign this intermediate boolean to a variable.

Your particular problem is that `return` is a statement and cannot be part of an expression. If at all, the code needs to look like:

```
$result = $number == 100 ? true : false;
return $result;
```

But again, that can be reduced to the version above.

Comment: Good answer. I added some extra information so the OP knows in the future.